# Restore Subversion from file backups

Tags: ubuntu, backup, svn, restore

I recently had to send in my computer for repairs, and my hard drive ended up getting replaced. Luckily I had a backup of the files, but no system image.

I'd like to get my SVN repositories back, but I don't have a dump out of SVN, just the repository directories on the hard drive.

Is there a way to rebuild my SVN repositories from just the files on the hard drive without having a dump file? How do I do that?

Comment: Have you read [the book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/)?

Comment: I have, it mentions using hot-backup or svnadmin dump to backup your repositories. It's already too late for me, I just have the filesystem backup, with no hot-backup or dump file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have a backup or not?

If you have a backup, just put the backuped files for the SVN repositories to the place where they belong. To check them first, just run

```
svnadmin dump /path/to/backuped/repos >> /dev/null
```

Comment: So I created a new blank repository on the new system. Then ran your command `svnadmin dump /path/to/backuped/repos >> dump_file` then ran an `svnadmin load /path/to/backuped/repos < dump_file` and it appears that the repositories are back in there. Thanks.